# JavaScript: x.split is not a function error

Tags: javascript

I have been working on converting a number to a string, then to an array and adding each array value together. I am running into an error where it says, "x.split is not a function in arr". Any solutions?

```js
function quan(x) {
    str(x);
    arr(x);
    int(x);
    return x;
}

function str(x) {
    return x.toString();
}
function arr(x) {
    return x.split("");
}
function int(x) {
    return parseFloat(x);
}

console.log(quan(13));
```

Comment: What do you mean "each array value"? Do you mean each digit of the number?

Comment: You should assign the returned value to x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of the functions you are calling returns a new value—they do not modify the value in place, so when you call `split`, `x` is still a number, and you can't split a number.

Try running this in a console to see what I mean:

```
x = 13
console.log(x.toString()) # output: "13"
console.log(x, typeof x) # output: 13 "string"
```

Instead, you need to re-assign `x` or create new variables.

```
x = 13
x = x.toString() # now x is the string "13"
y = x.split("") # y is ["1", "3"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a composition function approach.

```js
function compose(...fns) {
    return function(arg) {
      return fns.reduce((acc, fn) => fn(acc), arg);
    }
}

function str(x) {
    return x + '';
}
function arr(x) {
    return x.split("");
}
function int(x) {
    return parseFloat(x);
}

const compositionFn = compose(str, arr, int);

console.log(compositionFn(22));
```

Answer (score 0):

Spelling error?  I looked at this many times and thought my IDE was broken, searched stack overflow for str.split is not a function.  turns out on closer inspection I had written **str.spilt** and dam if it looks the same on a casual glance. So the problem was me not the ide or javascript.